# opencv2 bluring images

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to blur an image , and gaussion blur an image but all that ends up happening when i run my code is the image opens up without bluring.  Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

 int main() {
//read the image
cv::Mat image= cv::imread("Space_Nebula.jpg");
cv::Mat result;
// create image window
cv::namedWindow("My Image");
//display image
cv::imshow("My Image", image);
//wait key
cv::waitKey(50000);

//blur image
cv::blur(image,result,cv::Size(5,5));
cv::imshow("My Image", image);

//smooth image
cv::GaussianBlur(image,result,cv::Size(5,5),1.5);
cv::imshow("My Image", image);

return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple things: You are processing `image` into the Mat called `result` but then displaying `image`. Also, there is no call to waitKey after the last two calls to `imshow` so you aren't seeing those at all. And a small point: return 0 from `main` to signal completion with no error. Try this instead:

```
//read the image
cv::Mat image= cv::imread("../../IMG_0080.JPG");
cv::Mat result;
// create image window
cv::namedWindow("My Image");
//display image
cv::imshow("My Image", image);
//wait key
cv::waitKey(0);

//blur image
cv::blur(image,result,cv::Size(5,5));
cv::imshow("My Image", result);
cv::waitKey(0);

//smooth image
cv::GaussianBlur(image,result,cv::Size(5,5),1.5);
cv::imshow("My Image", result);
cv::waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `cv::imshow("My Image", result);` instead of `cv::imshow("My Image", image);`.